# Issues with Porto Theme basic tables with Advance Tools

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have JSON data and from that i am building my Table. Below is an extract of my code.

```
var table = '';
table = " <table class='table table-bordered table-striped mb-0' id='datatable-tabletools'>";
table += "<thead>";
table += "<tr>";
table += "<th> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'></i> Actions</th>";

table += "<th>PAX</th>";
table += "<th>Group No</th>";
table += "<th>Group Name</th>";

table += "</tr>";
table += "</thead>";

table += "<tbody>";

for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    table += "<tr>";

    table += "<td>" + data[j]["PAX"] + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + (data[j]["GroupNo"] == undefined ? '' : data[j]["GroupNo"]) + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + (data[j]["GroupName"] == undefined ? '' : data[j]["GroupName"]) + "</td>";

    table += "</tr>";
}

table += "</tbody>";
table += "</table>";

$('#gridContainer').html(table);
$("table#datatable-tabletools").dataTable();
```

As you can see in the code above I am trying to append it to a div with id="gridContainer". Up till here I have things up and running as required but the issue is my EXPORT bar doesn't appear at all. Currently, the searching, sorting functionalities and the table structure are all fine. Below is a screenshot of how it looks currently.

[image]

But when i declare a static table instead of appending the table to a DIV tag it appears fine and the exporting options also appear and are functiona. This is how the top header looks then

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: you can position buttons by sending dom object to the datatables https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: how? I think maybe i need to play around with DOM object actually so that the export options display on top. The issue is how? i don't really know :X. Also, as i mentioned above, exporting works perfectly when i have a static table. But when i populate it as a dynamic table, the exporting doesn't show up at all!!...